# Common Disclosures for multiple applications?

Tags: disclosure, start-ups

We are a lean startup and looking out for ways to define our patent strategy.

Is it possible to file multiple applications, each application with invention-focussed modifications to the specification to cover the problem and the solution claimed by that specific application?

Basically, we intend to reuse the text of the parent application with some modifications for the subsequent application (based on the new problem it solves) and drafting a new claim set.

We see this as a strategy to lower legal costs for the technical team producing incremental and improvement innovations.

Please provide some examples if you have analyzed some of the patent applications disclosing incremental and improvement innovations?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much standard. Multiple priorities, cip, etc.

Comment: Are you asking about having a common generic part of the description for multiple inventions? Like essentially boilerplate text describing what a computer is, what a system might involve, that sort of thing? Or something else?

Comment: @Maca I meant something than boilerplate text. I want to identify which part of the specification essentially must be changed and to what extent? Is it sufficient to change background section and detailed description with three or four paragraphs, keeping drawings and brief summary the same?